# Rails MySQL Temporary Table Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to build a temporary table in rails given the action defined below:

```
 def testCreate
    insert = 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (
              location varchar(10)
              );

              CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test2 (
              campaign varchar(10)
              );

              INSERT INTO test
              VALUES' +  params[:insert_location_csv].to_s + ';

              INSERT INTO test2
              VALUES(' + params[:campaign_id].to_s + ');

              INSERT INTO campaign_locations(campaign_id, location_id, created_at, updated_at)
              select 
              a.campaign  as campaign_id
              ,b.location as location_id
              ,NOW()      as created_at
              ,NOW()      as updated_at
              from test2 a
                cross join test b'

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(insert)
end
```

In MySQL workbench the query executes fine, but when attempting to access this action through the route: `http://localhost:3000/testCreate/70/(101),(102)` the error appears below as:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test2 ( campaign varchar(10) ); INSERT' at line 5: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test ( location varchar(10) ); CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test2 ( campaign varchar(10) ); INSERT INTO test VALUES(101),(102); INSERT INTO test2 VALUES(70); INSERT INTO campaign_locations(campaign_id, location_id, created_at, updated_at) select a.campaign as campaign_id ,b.location as location_id ,NOW() as created_at ,NOW() as updated_at from test2 a cross join test b
```

How can I prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: you are trying to execute 5 queries in one execute, which fails. Split the queries and run one each. The Workbench does handle one each, behind the scene. Thats why it works fine there.

Comment: So it would simply resemble: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query1) ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query2) ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query3)...etc in the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass one valid sql query `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` method. You are passing a set of sql queries and expecting it to work in one call.

The following should work:

```
create_tmp_table = 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (
          location varchar(10)
          );

 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(create_tmp_table)
```

Documentation : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute

Comment: I need them all executed. Do I simply then pass multiple?

Comment: Call each of them separately.

Comment: Wouldn't that result with temporary tables becoming inaccessible because it only exists for the lifespan of the SQL query execution?